# Azure Pipeline How to split Build.BuildNumber variable in stage variables and pass it's first part as parameter to downstream job

Tags: azure, variables, yaml, pipeline

I want to split Build.BuildNumber predefined variable in stage variables section and pass the splitted first part(current date) to downstream job

I tried splitting it directly in stage variables section using split function of azure pipelines, but it's returning empty.

Comment: If you use `ubuntu-latest` virtual machine then you can use `awk`, `cut`, `sed`, or other Linux commands that can split your environment variable.